Image on face probelm
I have been working with this Roblox head at least 3 hours, I wanna add an image to the front, but it just goes in weird ways.
I don't understand why does it also repeat while I have selected everything to clipping.
I have watched all UV unwrapping tutorials but they don't seem to help.
I don't even understand what's happening here anymore.


Hello, as you see, your UVs are really messy so it's logical that the projected image looks messy, maybe share your file so that we find the best way to unwrap? Don't forget to pack your images (File > External Data > Pack Resources)

Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see How to take a screenshot. Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see How to take a screenshot. Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.
